# jQuery filter posts by their first letter - Alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, woocommerce, elementor

I have a list of products originating from WooCommerce, being pulled in as a custom post (using the page builder Elementor) here: http://staging.morningsidepharm.com/products/generic-medicines/

I have used a plugin to try and add an alphabetical filter, but this isn't working for me (I think because I'm displaying the products as posts) so I thought I would use jquery to build one.

I've found the following code:

HTML

```
<button class="active btn" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" id="a">Show A</button>
<button class="btn" id="b">Show B</button>
<button class="btn" id="c">Show C</button>
<button class="btn" id="d">Show D</button>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="box a b">A &amp; B</div>
  <div class="box a">A</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
.btn {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}
.spacer {
  clear: both;
  height: 20px;
}
```

JS

```
var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'all') {
    $('#parent > div').fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    var $el = $('.' + this.id).fadeIn(450);
    $('#parent > div').not($el).hide();
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Which can be seen in action here: https://codepen.io/terf/pen/vGeqC

This seems to work because each div has a class of a, b, c, d, etc.

However, in my case, each of my container divs would have the same class, but would have a unique h3 title for example:

```
<div class="product"><h3>Acarbose</h3></div>
<div class="product"><h3>Bicalutamide</h3></div>
<div class="product"><h3>Capecitabine</h3></div>
<div class="product"><h3>Dapsone</h3></div>
```

So I think, to make this work, I need the jQuery to read the first letter of the h3 inside each of the product divs, then only display the corresponding products when the letter filter is pressed.

Or add the name of the product into the div as a class perhaps?

I know this is just a starting point, and there might be an easier way to achieve this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would add a parameter, something like <div class="product" key="A"><h3>Acarbose</h3></div>. Then you can retrieve this parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting the first letter to search for from the `id` of the clicked button. Therefore you can just `filter()` the `.product` elements by a Regular Expression which ensures they start with that letter, something like this:

```js
var $boxes = $('#parent > .box');

var $btns = $('.btn').click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  if (id == 'all') {
    $boxes.fadeIn(450);
  } else {
    $boxes.fadeOut(450).filter(function() {
      var re = new RegExp('^' + id, 'i');
      return re.test($(this).text().trim());
    }).stop(true).fadeIn(450);
  }
  $btns.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.btn {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px;
}

.active {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.box {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #fff;
}

.spacer {
  clear: both;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="active btn" id="all">Show All</button>
<button class="btn" id="a">Show A</button>
<button class="btn" id="b">Show B</button>
<button class="btn" id="c">Show C</button>
<button class="btn" id="d">Show D</button>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Acarbose</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Bicalutamide</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Capecitabine</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Dapsone</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great - I was able to understand and alter it to fit my use case! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Sorry, is it possible to do this without fade? When I initially filter the products then all fade out one by one - I tried this, but its not right - var $boxes = $('.elementor-posts-container > .elementor-post');

var $btns = $('.alphabet-btn').click(function() {
  var id = this.id;
  if (id == 'all') {
    $boxes.;
  } else {
    $boxes.filter(function() {
      var re = new RegExp('^' + id, 'i');
      return re.test($(this).text().trim());
    }).stop(true);
  }
  $btns.removeClass('alphabet-active');
  $(this).addClass('alphabet-active');
})

Comment: Sure, just change `fadeIn(450)` to `show()` and `fadeOut(450)` to `hide()`: http://jsfiddle.net/8dh0mnf7/

Comment: That's great, however, it seems to fail on the first click? If you visit here and click on B, for example, http://staging.morningsidepharm.com/products/generic-medicines/ it shows the drug beginning with B then it fades in a few other drugs... but then when I navigate around its ok.. its just the initial click that seems weird?

Comment: I would guess you've got another event handler tied to the button click which needs to be removed

Comment: I have a piece of jquery in the samAh Ive got it, I have this further up in the document: jQuery(".elementor-post").each(function(i) {
    jQuery(this).delay(250 * i).fadeIn(1000);
});